# Chromecast not connecting when TP - Link modem has password for wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, router, passwords, wireless-router, chromecast

My Google Chromecast connects to wifi only when i put no password to the wifi. The moment i put wifi with password, it refuses to connect.

I am using TP-Link model no. TD-W89551ND wi-fi modem.

I use authentication type WPA-PSK when i put password on my wifi.

kindly advise.

Comment: where do i check this input format? on the modem?

Comment: i am not certain i understood you. But the wi-fi connects to chromecast when i don't put password to wifi. does that mean the settings permit the chromecast to connect, but somehow the authentication or its type is causing problems?

Comment: Rereading your question, the authentication must match at both ends.  If connection with no password works, it means that the other end isn't configured for password authentication.  You can't use authentication on just one side of a connection.  Wireless output devices like printers don't use password authentication, even when connected to a modem that does.  It may be the same for Chromecast.

Comment: yes, so i think its not a modem compatibility issue. but authentications should be standard, and chromecast should be capable of handling it. hence the puzzle continues.

Comment: I found some instructions for Chromecast.  It appears to have an app that you use to configure it, and there is a place to enter the password.  Is that what you're referring to?  If so, that has to match the modem's setting.  If that connects with no password, I would think it means that the modem is not set for authentication.  Can you clarify your modem's settings and where you are doing this setup?

Comment: yes, i'm using the chromecast app. and i enter the password there. i am not changing any modem settings. I tried both the WPA-PSK and WPA2-PSK authentication type. no effect!

Comment: hey! i changed the encryption to AES! and its working now! i'm very happy. Thanks for your help dear! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the WPA2-PSK authentication type. 
And changed encryption to AES from TKIP/AES.

Its connected to the wifi with password now! Yay! :)